# How do I act on server-side validation errors returned from an http call in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

By following various guides, I've developed a service that I can call to send login details to the backend for validation and action. I'm able to return decent error codes based on the input, but then what?

```js
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getUserDetails(email, password){
        // post to API server - return user info if valid

        return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/listee/task_login.php', {
            email,
            password
        }).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data, 'returned from login attempt')
            var theData: any;
            theData = data;
            if (theData.post_err || theData.email_err)
                console.log('ak;dsfj');
        })
    }
}
```

The data is returned to a function of a class... how can I act on the form elements from inside that scope? I need to somehow trigger error codes in Angular on the correct form elements. How can i access them? Do I need to just manually select document.getElementByID or is there a more sophisticated/correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that getUserDetail should be an Observable.

```
export class AuthService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getUserDetails(email, password): Observable<any> {
// post to API server - return user info if valid

    return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/listee/task_login.php', {
        email,
        password
        })
       // .subscribe(data => {
       //      console.log(data, 'returned from login attempt')
       //      var theData: any;
       //      theData = data;
       //      if (theData.post_err || theData.email_err)
       //      console.log('ak;dsfj');
       //  })
    }
}
```

In your component, you could subscribe to this method and read the result.

```
someMethod(): void {
    this.authService.getUserDetails(email,password).subscribe(result => { 
          //Do something with the result that you pass back in the component. 

    }
}
```

Instead of subscribing in the service, just let the component handle the subscription and whatever other logic needs to run.  The service should do one thing, getUserDetails, it shouldn't handle passing and manipulating of errors.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why the guide said subscribe -- observable does make more sense.

Comment: new problem: now that getUserDetails is an observable, it's returning an Observable and not the data returned from the getUserDetails function. How do I access that data?

Comment: Nevermind. I asked a second question and got the answer (observable in the service, subscribe in the calling component)

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see your comment until this morning.I'm glad you figured it out.